# Javascript/jQuery event handler isn't loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem using jQuery where the blocks of code inside `$(document).ready()` won't load. I have looked into it and haven't been able to find a solution. I looked at it with the chrome "inspect element" tool thing in the Event Listeners tab there is nothing for the object that has an event linked to it.

I'm using brackets and Jslint gives me the error: "$ was used before it was defined" for the first line of code. Here is my HTML code and Js/jQuery code:

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Java.js"></script>
    <style>
     #login{
        display:;
        font-size: 18;
        left: 80%;
        top: 28%;
    }

    #login:hover{
        opacity: 0.4;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #nav-icon{
        width: 20px;
        height: 15px;
        position: relative;
        top: 30%;
        left: 90%;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #nav-icon span{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 1px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 9px;
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    }

    #nav-icon span:nth-child(1) {
        top: 0px;
    }

    #nav-icon span:nth-child(2) {
        top: 6px;
    }

    #nav-icon span:nth-child(3) {
        top: 12px;
    }

    #nav-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
      top: 4.5px;
      left: 100;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
      transform: rotate(135deg);
    }

    #nav-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
      opacity: 0;
      left: -60px;
    }

    #nav-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
      top: 3px;
      left: 100;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
      transform: rotate(-135deg);
    }

    #menubar{
        display:;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 15%;
        left: 50%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
        z-index: 2;
        font-family: main;
        font-size: 20;
        color: fff;
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 2;   
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="HeaderContainer">
        <div class=header id="login">
            <li>Login</li>
        </div>

        <div id="nav-icon">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="menubar">
        <li>Login</li>
        <li>My Account</li>
        <li>My Wishlist</li>
        <li>My Orders</li> 
    </div>

</body>
```

**Js/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav-icon').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('#menubar').animate({left: 'toggle'}, -30%);
        $('#login').fadeToggle(fast);
    });
});
```

The HTML and JS are in separate files and I know that both JS files are correctly linked to the HTML file. `alert()` placed on the first line before any other code works.

What I want to happen:
I want the hamburger menu (#nav-icon) to, when clicked, toggle the CSS class "open".
When I click it right now nothing happens.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

PS: I'm new here so sorry if I messed anything up.

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: Tried using full path to `js` files ?

Comment: Can you try including the external `js` file(s) at the end of the HTML `<body>` @FarasatAhmed

Comment: The only error I get is inside the editor I use. I use brackets and Jslint gives me the error: "$ was used before it was defined".

Comment: I am assuming that your jQuery is in `JS/Java.js`?

Comment: @guest271314 What do you mean?

Comment: you have to include jquery file before your code. if it still doesn't work use fiddel and post link.

Comment: @JacobGray No its in a separate file in the JS folder. The file name is jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: @FarasatAhmed No, I mean your JS(Js/jQuery in your question) is in java.js

Comment: @chiragchavda.ks Where do I have to include it? I have it linked in the HTML file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @JacobGray Oh, then yes, it is `JS/Java.js`

Comment: @FarasatAhmed then the jQuery should be linking fine, does the answer below help?

Comment: @FarasatAhmed Have you tried including your JS files at the bottom of `<body>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`, -30%` not appear to be valid `duration` at `$('#menubar').animate({left: 'toggle'}, -30%);` ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav-icon').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('#menubar').animate({left: 'toggle'}, 1000);
        $('#login').fadeToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

```css
#login {
       display: ;
       font-size: 18;
       left: 80%;
       top: 28%;
     }
     #login:hover {
       opacity: 0.4;
       cursor: pointer;
     }
     #nav-icon {
       width: 20px;
       height: 15px;
       position: relative;
       top: 30%;
       left: 90%;
       -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
       transform: rotate(0deg);
       -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
       transition: .5s ease-in-out;
       cursor: pointer;
     }
     #nav-icon span {
       display: block;
       position: relative;
       height: 1px;
       width: 100%;
       background: #ffffff;
       border-radius: 9px;
       opacity: 1;
       left: 0;
       -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
       transform: rotate(0deg);
       -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
       transition: .25s ease-in-out;
     }
     #nav-icon span:nth-child(1) {
       top: 0px;
     }
     #nav-icon span:nth-child(2) {
       top: 6px;
     }
     #nav-icon span:nth-child(3) {
       top: 12px;
     }
     #nav-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
       top: 4.5px;
       left: 100;
       -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
       transform: rotate(135deg);
     }
     #nav-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
       opacity: 0;
       left: -60px;
     }
     #nav-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
       top: 3px;
       left: 100;
       -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
       transform: rotate(-135deg);
     }
     #menubar {
       display: ;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       height: 100%;
       width: 15%;
       left: 50%;
       background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
       z-index: 2;
       font-family: main;
       font-size: 20;
       color: fff;
       list-style: none;
       line-height: 2;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="HeaderContainer">
        <div class=header id="login">
            <li>Login</li>
        </div>

        <div id="nav-icon">
          <span>a</span>
          <span>b</span>
          <span>c</span>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="menubar">
        <li>Login</li>
        <li>My Account</li>
        <li>My Wishlist</li>
        <li>My Orders</li> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks! That did the job! I didn't know that one error could lead to all the code not working! Thanks!

Comment: @FarasatAhmed Note also `fast` not appear to be string `"fast"` as pointed out by @chiragchavda.ks

Answer (score 0):

this line is wrong.
 `$('#login').fadeToggle(fast);`

there no such thing like fast in jQuery Correct way is something like this :

`$('#login').fadeToggle('fast');`

you have to use `fast` as string.